# BeautifulSoup: Python: Trying to extract data from multiple rows

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to programming. I am trying to write a program to scrape the time the Moon sets in my local area (Tampa) and display it when I enter the date.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
def GetMoonSet():
  # setup the source
  with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/usa/tampa") as url:
    req = url.read()

  soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")
  the_rows = soup('table', {'id': "tb-7dmn"})[0].tbody('tr')

  day1 = the_rows[0].findChildren('td')
  day2 = the_rows[1].findChildren('td')
  day3 = the_rows[2].findChildren('td')
  day4 = the_rows[3].findChildren('td')
  day5 = the_rows[4].findChildren('td')
  day6 = the_rows[5].findChildren('td')
  day7 = the_rows[6].findChildren('td')
  day8 = the_rows[7].findChildren('td')
  day9 = the_rows[8].findChildren('td')
  day10 = the_rows[9].findChildren('td')
  day11 = the_rows[10].findChildren('td')
  day12 = the_rows[11].findChildren('td')
  day13 = the_rows[12].findChildren('td')
  day14 = the_rows[13].findChildren('td')
  day15 = the_rows[14].findChildren('td')
  day16 = the_rows[15].findChildren('td')
  day17 = the_rows[16].findChildren('td')
  day18 = the_rows[17].findChildren('td')
  day19 = the_rows[18].findChildren('td')
  day20 = the_rows[19].findChildren('td')
  day21 = the_rows[20].findChildren('td')
  day22 = the_rows[21].findChildren('td')
  day23 = the_rows[22].findChildren('td')
  day24 = the_rows[23].findChildren('td')
  day25 = the_rows[24].findChildren('td')
  day26 = the_rows[25].findChildren('td')
  day27 = the_rows[26].findChildren('td')
  day28 = the_rows[27].findChildren('td')
  day29 = the_rows[28].findChildren('td')
  day30 = the_rows[29].findChildren('td')

  what_date = input("Please enter a date for this month ")

  if what_date == "1":
    print("The moon will set at " + day1[1].text)
  elif what_date == "2":
    print("The moon will set at " + day2[1].text)
  elif what_date == "3":
    print("The moon will set at " + day3[1].text)
  elif what_date == "4":
    print("The moon will set at " + day4[1].text)
  elif what_date == "5":
    print("The moon will set at " + day5[1].text)
  elif what_date == "6":
    print("The moon will set at " + day6[1].text)
  elif what_date == "7":
    print("The moon will set at " + day7[1].text)
  elif what_date == "8":
    print("The moon will set at " + day8[1].text)
  elif what_date == "9":
    print("The moon will set at " + day9[1].text)
  elif what_date == "10":
    print("The moon will set at " + day10[1].text)
  elif what_date == "11":
    print("The moon will set at " + day11[1].text)
  elif what_date == "12":
    print("The moon will set at " + day12[1].text)
  elif what_date == "13":
    print("The moon will set at " + day13[1].text)
  elif what_date == "14":
    print("The moon will set at " + day14[1].text)
  elif what_date == "15":
    print("The moon will set at " + day15[1].text)
  elif what_date == "16":
    print("The moon will set at " + day16[1].text)
  elif what_date == "17":
    print("The moon will set at " + day17[1].text)
  elif what_date == "18":
    print("The moon will set at " + day18[1].text)
  elif what_date == "19":
    print("The moon will set at " + day19[1].text)
  elif what_date == "20":
    print("The moon will set at " + day20[1].text)
  elif what_date == "21":
    print("The moon will set at " + day21[1].text)
  elif what_date == "22":
    print("The moon will set at " + day22[1].text)
  elif what_date == "23":
    print("The moon will set at " + day23[1].text)
  elif what_date == "24":
    print("The moon will set at " + day24[1].text)
  elif what_date == "25":
    print("The moon will set at " + day25[1].text)
  elif what_date == "26":
    print("The moon will set at " + day26[1].text)
  elif what_date == "27":
    print("The moon will set at " + day27[1].text)
  elif what_date == "28":
    print("The moon will set at " + day28[1].text)
  elif what_date == "29":
    print("The moon will set at " + day29[1].text)
  elif what_date == "30":
    print("The moon will set at " + day30[1].text)
  else:
     print("Please enter a different number (e.g. 4, 5, 28, 30")

GetMoonSet()
```

I'm sure it doesn't look the greatest but I am having trouble with extracting the data. From day 4-17 there is a Moon Rise happening in the first column. When I ask for the data it is giving me one column off due to the new information. I know I could update 4-17 to be day4[2].text but this will be different next month and it wouldn't work anymore.

When I input 2 it displays:
The moon will set at 10:22 am

When I input 4 it displays:
The moon will set at ↑ (99°)

Am I doing this the hard way? Is there a way to only extract the time of the moonset by find_all?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't ask about "moonset and find_all", ask about about skipping empty table cells while iterating over table rows. You force readers to follow the link to answer your Q. Consider loops and check whether first element is a dash and, if so, pop it out from the array. Also consider caching results.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry about that, my first post here. I'll make sure to do it right next time.

Comment: Also consider calculating all that yourself instead of scrapping someone else's page. Might be a fun way to learn programming. Even if you don't want to work out the math yourself, quick googling shows https://github.com/mourner/suncalc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, use loops to repeatedly parse the moonset times and save the data in a dictionary so that you can later use it to extract a moonset time when the user inputs a date.

The following code achieves this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

# Initialize a dictionary
d = {}

# Function to extract moonset times
def GetMoonSet():
    global d

    print("Extracting moonset times...")
    # setup the source
    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/usa/tampa") as url:
        req = url.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")
    the_rows = soup('table', {'id': "tb-7dmn"})[0].tbody('tr')

    for row in the_rows:
        col_header = row.findChildren("th")[0]
        day = col_header.getText().strip(' \t\n\r')
        d[day] = 'NA'
        cols = row.findChildren("td")
        for col in cols:
            if col.get('title') != None and col.get('title').startswith("The Moon sets in") and col.get('class') != None and len(col.get('class')) == 2:
                d[day] = col.getText()
                continue

# Collect moonset times
GetMoonSet()

# Ask for date from user and print the corresponding moonset time
while True:
    date = input("Please enter a valid date for this month: ")
    if int(date) < 1 or int(date) > 31:
        continue
    else:
        print("Moonset time on {} is {}.".format(date, d[date]))
        break
```

This code will output:

```
Extracting moonset times...
Please enter a valid date for this month: 5
Moonset time on 5 is 1:01 pm.
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for helping me here. EDIT: It works exactly how I was looking for. Much Appreciated. Now I can take it apart backwards and learn from this.

Comment: @Matthew Np! If any of the answers helped you with your question, don't forget to accept the answer or upvote them.

Comment: Could you please explain what this is doing?: 
len(col.get('class')) == 2:

I am readng the HTML and not sure what it is seeing.

Comment: `len(col.get('class')) == 2`: It checks if the `class` attribute of `td` tag has exactly 2 values. `col.get('class')` determines the `td` tag's `class` attribute's value. `len()` determines the size of the list. Feel free to ask me more questions.

Answer (score 1):

That table looks like it was built to not be parsed! It looks like the `title` may be the key you need:

```
for i in soup.table.tbody.find_all(class_="pdr0", title=re.compile("^The Moon sets ")):
  print(i.get_text())
```

And, to make what you are trying a little more compact:

```
msets = {}
title=re.compile("^The Moon sets ")
for row in soup.table.tbody.find_all('tr'):
  day  = row['data-day']
  mset = row.find(title=title)
  if day and mset: msets[day] = mset.get_text()

what_date = input("Please enter a date for this month: ")
if what_date in msets:
  print("the moon will set at " + msets[what_date])
else:
  print("i don't know about that date.")
```

As a rule-of-thumb when programming - if you find yourself repeating the same thing over and over, you probably need a loop.

Comment: Thank you Keith. This was very easy to understand and figure out what was happening. I appreciate your time.